# Which sentence is it? Causative or imperative?

Tags: imperative-sentences

"Let not thine eyes be blind", my son.

I think it is imperative because it is just an advice to her son to take care of himself.

Comment: What do _you_ think?

Comment: I think it's ambiguous, in that it could be either "imperative" (speaker is urging the boy not to close his eyes to whatever is going on), OR "invocative" ("praying" to God that ***He*** will metaphorically open the boy's eyes). But I don't see any way for it to be "causative".

Comment: It's called an 'optative', a minor clause type that expresses wishes. Though it's a main clause, the plain form verb "be" marks it as a subjunctive construction.